# Mocking function inside another function using jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I'd like to mock a function which called by another function using jest but it doesn't work. The mock function is never called by the parent function.

app.js

```
const evaluate = (a, b) => {
  return 'Sum is ' + add(a, b);
}

const add = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
}

exports.evaluate = evaluate;
exports.add = add;
```

test.js

```
const evaluateService = require("./app");

describe('Call jumpRequest', () => {

  it('should return Evaluate', async () => {

    evaluateService.add = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(12);
    const res = await evaluateService.evaluate(5, 3);
    expect(res).toEqual("Sum is 12");
 })
})
```

Comment: *Don't* mock that, it's part of the same module. If it's complex enough to actually need separate testing (I'd argue not in this case), extract it to a separate module.

Comment: Thanks, So here is an abstraction for what i want to do but If I can't isolate a function to test it even in the same module, what's the interests of test. Indeed sometimes I need to isolate and test a function from other because of multiple function chain calls.

Comment: Possibly the example isn't representative, but I'd still give the same advice - extract *collaborators* to replace with test doubles, but internal reuse of functions (and therefore refactoring *within* the module boundary) shouldn't involve mocks.

Comment: Do you have any resources  please (links, book title or whatever) to explore deeply your advice and understand how to test correctly because on youtube and internet many people test like that.

Comment: Recommendations are off topic here, but http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/ and http://codemanship.co.uk/tdd_jasongorman_codemanship.pdf are good.

Comment: Change `return 'Sum is ' + add(a, b);` to `return 'Sum is ' + exports.add(a, b);`

Comment: Yes it enables to point to the same scope, Thanks.